# webix combo options value in html Initialization

Tags: javascript, html, webix

I'm using Webix UI. I want to do something like

```
<div view="combo" options="fruit"></div>
```

in my js:

```
$scope.fruit =[{id:1, value: "Apple"}, {id:2, value: "Banana"}];
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: I got the answer from webix forum. <div view="combo" options="-" webix-data="fruit">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from webix forum.

```
<div view="combo" options="-" webix-data="fruit">
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
<div data-view="combo">
  <config stack="options">
    <li id="1">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2">Item 2</li>
  </config>
</div>
```